# How to safely erase elements in a std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator

I'm getting segfault errors when I use the `erase()` method in a `class vector` container.

I'm comparing two vectors and, so I want to remove from one of them the elements that are not present in the another. To do so, I'm using iterators and `erase()` as follow:

```
#include <vector>

int main () {

std::vector<int> vector1 {6,7,5,44,3,10,9,17,1};
std::vector<int> vector2 {1,2,3,5,8};

for (std::vector<int>::iterator it (vector2.begin()); it != vector2.end(); ++it) {
    bool equal (false);
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator jt (vector1.begin()); jt != vector1.end(); ++jt) {
        if (*it == *jt) {
            equal = true;
            break       ;
        }
    }
    if (!equal) {
        vector2.erase(it);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

What is causing the segfault is the deletion of the last element in `vector2` (`8`), because `erase()` cannot succesfully move the iterator from the previous `end()` position (no longer existant) to a new one.

How can this be prevented? I'm aware that `unordered_set` could be a proper container for this operation, but here I'm interested in `vector`.

Comment: The standard way to do this is called the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)

Comment: If you really want to do it the way you are trying to do it, I would iterate through vector1 in the outer loop, and vector 2 in the inner loop.  That way you are not deleting from the vector in the outer loop and disturbing the validity of the iterators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't remove like:

```
if (!equal) {
    vector2.erase(it);
}
```

`erase` operation invalidates `it`, so the next `++it` is an error.

Instead of it, you might rewrite the outer cycle as:

```
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it (vector2.begin()); it != vector2.end();)
```

and change `it` inside the `for` loop:

```
if (!equal) {
    it = vector2.erase(it);
} else {
    ++it;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JEtW0iTGYrzDd1Lk)

---

Note, that you might use *remove-erase idiom* as well:

```
vector2.erase(
    std::remove_if(std::begin(vector2), std::end(vector2), [&vector1](const auto& e) {
        return std::find(std::cbegin(vector1), std::cend(vector1), e) == std::end(vector1);
    }),
    std::end(vector2)
);
```

which is a standard way to do the things like this.

Comment: Thank you! this solves the problem, and I understand better it now

Answer (score 3):

The problem, as others have pointed out, is that erasing invalidates your iterator.  But there's a more general issue here in using raw loops to do this sort of manipulation.  It requires a lot of boilerplate code and is error prone.  You can use the standard algorithms to avoid these pitfalls.

```
std::vector<int> result;
std::sort(vector1.begin(), vector1.end());
std::sort(vector2.begin(), vector2.end());
std::set_difference(
  vector2.begin(),
  vector2.end(),
  vector1.begin(),
  vector1.end(),
  std::back_inserter(result));
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your iterators are invalidated after erasing. Change this:

```
vector2.erase(it);
```

to this:

```
it = vector2.erase(it);
```

And it would be a step toward solving the problem. Check the [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/), and you'd see that the return value is the next valid iterator.